# No boot on Ubuntu 20.04 or 18.04 with ThinkPad T430u without nolapic option

Tags: boot, kernel, thinkpad

After Ubuntu 18.04 kernel upgrades, I am unable to boot. The screen only shows "loading initram disk" and then freezes. The last bootable version was 4.15.0-72.

Recently installed Ubuntu 20.04, and the problem persists with the new 5.4 Kernel (tested with 5.4.0-42 and 5.4.0-42).

I can boot with the "nolapic" kernel parameter, but it disables multiple CPU cores.

My laptop is a ThinkPad T430u.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I also have to boot with `noapic` or it never loads the initial RAM disk on OpenSUSE 15.2 Leap for ThinkPad T430u.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved on kernel 5.8.0-43, [which ships with the 20.04.2 image.](https://www.neowin.net/news/canonical-releases-second-point-release-of-ubuntu-2004-lts)

Comment: Problem appeared again on 5.8.0-59 and 5.8.0-63-generic, on LTS 20.04.2.

Adding kernel option intremap=off at grub menu made it.

Details:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1808418/comments/53